# How do I determine input as an integer and the length, simultaneously?

Tags: python, loops, integer

Ok so I'm really new to programming. My program asks the user to enter a '3 digit number'... and I need to determine the length of the number (make sure it is no less and no more than 3 digits) at the same time I test to make sure it is an integer. This is what I have:

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Please enter a (3 digit) number: "))
    except:
        print('try again')
    else:
        break
```

any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Does `012`count as 3 digits, or 2? You could always cast the number back to a string and look at the length: `len(str(number))`. Plus you would have to  perform additional validation for cases like `12.3`, etc. (`isdigit` would be handy here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`input()` returns you a string. So you can first check the length of that number, and length is not 3 then you can ask the user again. If the length is 3 then you can use that string as a number by `int()`. `len()` gives you the length of the string.

```
while True:
    num = input('Enter a 3 digit number.')
    if len(num) != 3:
        print('Try again')
    else:
        num = int(num)
        break
```

Comment: Also, if you want to use the same thing in python 2.x you should use 'raw_input()' instead of 'input()'. Because python is not backward compatible, issues often comes. Also you can up vote the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this in your try/except clause. Modify as necessary.

```
number_string = input("Please enter a (3 digit) number: ")
number_int = int(number_string)
number_length = len(number_string)
if number_length == 3:
    break
```

You could also use an `assert` to raise an exception if the length of the number is not 3.

```
try:
    assert number_length == 3
except AssertionError:
    print("Number Length not exactly 3")
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep the input in a variable before casting it into an int to check its length:

```
my_input = input("Please enter a (3 digit) number: ")
if len(my_input) != 3:
    raise ValueError()
number = int(my_input)
```

Note that `except:` alone is a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice). You should target your exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    inp = raw_input("Enter : ")
    length = len(inp)
    if(length!=3):
        raise ValueError
    num = int(inp)
```

In case you are using Python 2.x refrain from using `input`. Always use `raw_input`.

If you are using Python 3.x it is fine.

[Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
while True:
    try:
        string = input("Please enter a (3 digit) number: ")
        number = int(string)
        if len(string) != 3 or any(not c.isdigit() for c in string):
            raise ValueError()
    except ValueError:
        print('try again')
    else:
        break
```